# Calculating Permutations From a Fixed Starting Position

Tags: excel, vba, permutation

In **Column A**, starting from A1 is a list of 5 products.
In **Column B**, there is a 1 next to the very first product indicating that this is fixed, i.e.

- Product A - 1
- Product B
- Product C
- Product D
- Product E

I have already figured out how to calculate all of the permutations for these 5 products, giving me 120 rows of possibilities. See code below:

```
Sub Permutations_5_From_5()
    Dim rRng As Range
    Dim lRow As Long
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False: .Calculation = xlCalculationManual: .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With
    Range("C:G").ClearContents
    Set rRng = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown))
    For P1 = 1 To rRng.Count
        For P2 = 1 To rRng.Count
            For P3 = 1 To rRng.Count
                For P4 = 1 To rRng.Count
                    For P5 = 1 To rRng.Count
                        If _
                            P1 <> P2 And _
                            P1 <> P3 And _
                            P1 <> P4 And _
                            P1 <> P5 And _
                            P2 <> P3 And _
                            P2 <> P4 And _
                            P2 <> P5 And _
                            P3 <> P4 And _
                            P3 <> P5 And _
                            P4 <> P5 Then
                            lRow = lRow + 1
                            Range("C" & lRow) = Range("A" & P1)
                            Range("D" & lRow) = Range("A" & P2)
                            Range("E" & lRow) = Range("A" & P3)
                            Range("F" & lRow) = Range("A" & P4)
                            Range("G" & lRow) = Range("A" & P5)
                        End If
                    Next P5
                Next P4
            Next P3
        Next P2
    Next P1
    Range("A1").Select
    With Application
        .DisplayAlerts = True: .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic: .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

How would i only calculate permutations that all start from a **fixed product** (i.e. Product A) which should reduce this to 60 rows of possibilities?

Thanks,

Jordan